# Problem with uploading video to youtube by Youtube Data API V3

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

i'm trying to upload a short video to my channel by a python script using "Youtube Data Api v3"

its a splitscreen video with some podcast on top and some minecraft gameplay on bottom (you saw them everywhere...)

the problem is when i set that video to public, it immediately get "Terms and policies" Restriction and Visibility go to " Private (locked) ".

then i receive an email that says :

...Our team has reviewed your content, and we think you may need to make changes to make sure it doesn't violate our spam, deceptive practices and scams policy. ...

but when i upload the video manually, it works fine.

can somebody tell me whats the problem and how to fix it?